# Autoit get ram windows XP

Tags: autoit, ram

I have this code so far:

```
$ram=(_GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory()/1024)/1024
msgbox("RAM","RAM:",$ram)
Func _GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory()
    $aRet = DllCall("Kernel32.dll", "int", "GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory", "uint64*", "")
    If @error Then Return SetError(1, 0, 0)
    Return $aRet[1]
EndFunc
```

The code above works well with windows vista and up but it doesn't seem to work on XP does any one know what is wrong with it. Thanks.

Comment: given that xp is a 32bit os, it's highly unlikely it'd ever return more than a 32bit int for ram size.

Comment: @MarcB How do you think i should do it.

Comment: @09stephenb check whether the machine is 32bit or 64bit, then put in the coinciding bit int for ram size.

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove Would `uint64` work, i am on 64 bit so i cant test it.

Comment: Can you still test on the XP machine? @09stephenb

Comment: Have a look at `@OSArch` - https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/macros.htm @09stephenb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Local $aMem = MemGetStats()
MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Total physical RAM (KB): " & $aMem[1])
```

Comment: Thanks. When i run it i get 7543060 and it should return 8GB.

Comment: Returns a seven-element array containing the memory information:
    $aArray[0] = Memory Load (Percentage of memory in use)
    $aArray[1] = Total physical RAM
    $aArray[2] = Available physical RAM
    $aArray[3] = Total Pagefile
    $aArray[4] = Available Pagefile
    $aArray[5] = Total virtual
    $aArray[6] = Available virtual

All memory sizes are in kilobytes. So, you need a /1024/1024

Comment: I added `$ram=$aMem[1]
$ram=$ram/1024
$ram=$ram/1024` But i got a long number closer to 7 than 8.

Comment: There is 1024 MB in one GB So 7877 MB Would be 7.6923828125GB. See this [online converter](http://www.convertunits.com/from/MB/to/GB).